# Parsing multiple XML fields into meta data (custom fields)

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to find the correct PHP code for creating multiple meta values from an XML feed.

Currently I'm copying code from another part of the plugin to start with. It does create the first custom field, but I need it to do the same thing for the next 5 XML fields.

XML Snippet:

```
<menu_items type="array">
<menu_item>
<description/>
<gluten_free type="boolean">false</gluten_free>
<id type="integer">18780</id>
<name>Gyro Wrap</name>
<vegan type="boolean">false</vegan>
<vegetarian type="boolean">false</vegetarian>
<formatted_price>Min: $6.00 Max: $0.00</formatted_price>
</menu_item>
<menu_item>
<description/>
<gluten_free type="boolean">false</gluten_free>
<id type="integer">18781</id>
<name>Chicken Shawerma Wrap</name>
<vegan type="boolean">false</vegan>
<vegetarian type="boolean">false</vegetarian>
<formatted_price>Min: $6.00 Max: $0.00</formatted_price>
</menu_item>
<menu_item>
<description/>
<gluten_free type="boolean">false</gluten_free>
<id type="integer">18782</id>
<name>Spicy Chicken Wrap</name>
<vegan type="boolean">false</vegan>
<vegetarian type="boolean">false</vegetarian>
<formatted_price>Min: $7.00 Max: $0.00</formatted_price>
</menu_item>
<menu_item>
<description/>
<gluten_free type="boolean">false</gluten_free>
<id type="integer">18783</id>
<name>Falafel Wrap</name>
<vegan type="boolean">false</vegan>
<vegetarian type="boolean">true</vegetarian>
<formatted_price>Min: $6.00 Max: $0.00</formatted_price>
</menu_item>
<menu_item>
<description/>
<gluten_free type="boolean">false</gluten_free>
<id type="integer">18784</id>
<name>Baklava</name>
<vegan type="boolean">false</vegan>
<vegetarian type="boolean">true</vegetarian>
<formatted_price>Min: $3.00 Max: $0.00</formatted_price>
</menu_item>
</menu_items>
```

I need to EACH  field into it's own custom field.

Current code within plugin:

```
        $post_meta = array();
        if(!empty($vendor->menu_items)){
            $i = 0;
            foreach($vendor->menu_items->menu_item->name as $menu_item_name){
                $post_meta["marcato_menu_name_".$i] = $menu_item_name;
                $i++;
            }
        }
```

[single custom field showing up on WordPress, but I need 5 different ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0hAF.png)

I am in the process of learning PHP so forgive my newbness.. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through `$vendor->menu_items->menu_item->name` you could loop through `$vendor->menu_items->menu_item` and per menu_item use the `name` property.

The `$menu_item->name` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) so you could cast it to a `(string)`.

```
if(!empty($vendor->menu_items)){
    $i = 0;
    foreach($vendor->menu_items->menu_item as $menu_item){
        $post_meta["marcato_menu_name_".$i] = (string)$menu_item->name;
        $i++;
    }
}
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/tGOgj)